# setHeaderData not working + qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

I am trying to make a library management software. I am using Qt and Sqlite3. In my main window constructor, i have this piece of code

@ellyanesc, added this on  your recommendation:

```
db = QSqlDatabase :: addDatabase("QSQLITE");
model = new QSqlTableModel(this);

//QHeaderView view(Qt::Horizontal, this);
fileName = "Unnamed";

if(db.open())
{
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.exec("CREATE TABLE DEFAULT (NAME CHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, AUTHOR CHAR(100) NOT NULL, UID CHAR(100)) ");

    db.setDatabaseName("/home/hemil/Documents/libre coupe.db");
    model->setTable("DEFAULT");
    model->select();

    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("NAME") );
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("AUTHOR") );
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("UID") );
}

ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

No error shown but header does not show up

Comment: @eyllanesc would you help me again? Thank you

Comment: Where did you indicate the table? use: `model->setTable("your_tablename");` `model->select();`

Comment: Edit your question and add it there, it is horrible to put a lot of code in the comments, it is not readable

Comment: Check it now @eyllanesc. It still doesnt work

Comment: _"not working"_ is not a problem description... Why not? What happened? Why was that bad?

Comment: Still does not show the header and the error: QSqlQuery::exec: database not open @eyllanesc

Comment: @Hemil the setDatabaseName() you must indicate before opening it, but how do you know what to open?. Have you reviewed my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to indicate where your database is located and open it, You should not use DEFAULT since it is a reserved word in SQL, change it to another name:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("database.db");

if(db.open()){
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(!query.exec("CREATE TABLE MYDEFAULT IF NOT EXISTS (NAME CHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, AUTHOR CHAR(100) NOT NULL, UID CHAR(100)) ")){
        qDebug()<<query.lastError().text();
    }

    model = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    model->setTable("MyDEFAULT");
    model->select();

    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("NAME") );
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("AUTHOR") );
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("UID") );
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}
```

Comment: The error in application output is gone. But still no header in shown

Comment: @Hemil change DEFAULT to another name, that word is reserved in SQL